# Он упоминал Вас или о Вас?

Tags: падежи, предлоги

"Он Вас упоминал" или "он о Вас упоминал"? Как правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Он упоминал **вас** = называл ваше имя (по какому-то поводу).

Он упоминал **о вас** = упоминал вас по известному нам с вами поводу 
(напр. не раз упоминал о том, что вы тоже приходили туда).

Comment: А разве словосочетание *предлог «о» + сущ.* сочетается с личными местоимениями? Думаю, что *говорят о ком-то*, но *упоминают кого-то*.

Comment: Пример: В.Я. Брюсов, Маленькие драмы Пушкина; http://dugward.ru/library/brusov/brusov_malenkie_dramy.html
В обществе старались _не упоминать о ней_ в присутствии автора...

Answer (score 4):

Возможны оба варианта, но с разными значениями.

УПОМЯНУТЬ, -мяну, -мянешь; упомянутый; -нут, -а, -о; св. 1. **о ком-чём, про кого-что или с придат. дополнит. Бегло, вскользь коснуться чего-л., сообщить о ком-, чём-л.** Ни словом не у. о случившемся. У. о приятеле. 
2. **кого-что**. ***Произнести, назвать в разговоре. У. имя учителя. Ненароком у. кого-л.*** У. в разговоре известного поэта. // Назвать при перечислении. У. в списке награждённых.

> См.: Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
>   Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.